# Why is my Character Controller sticking to everything?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The Character Controller basically glues/sticks to every object which makes many aspects of it very inconsistent. Like sticking to the corners of objects or not falling down properly and so on. I have tried Brackey's controller, the Unity docs official controller and I've tested at least a dozen other controllers from both YouTube and GitHub in the last 2 months including my own, all which have the exact same problem. I have found similar questions on the internet all which have had no solutions, so is this something that I should just ignore if I decide to continue using the Character Controller component?

https://streamable.com/5td2pb

The grey rectangle is supposed to act as ground (or just any surface), so my player should fall off almost immediately after I begin to rotate the rectangle. I also am unsure of how to use physics with the controller as I can't attach a collider since I'm already using the controller component so setting friction with a Physic Material is not ideal from what I understand. I have tried to use a Raycast and SphereCast but they only mask the problem and don't provide an actual solution.

Comment: You could check for the slope limit variable.

Comment: Yeah I do have a slope limit already, but all it does is prevent my player from moving further upwards but it still doesn't solve the issue of the controller collider sticking to the surface at extreme angles etc like in the video

Comment: You could try to add a physics material to the slope. It could be unity uses default friction 1 when nothing else.